# Update multiple records in single query using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables in my MySql database:

Users Table:

```
  id   |   name   |   balance   
---------------------------------
     5    |   john    |     10000
     7    |   mike    |     12000
     8    |   jane    |     5680
```

Deposit Table:

```
   id   |   name  |   userId  | amount
-------------------------------------------
     1    |   D1    |     5       | 500
     2    |   D2    |     7       | 1000
     3    |   D2    |     8       | 1500
```

Now, I have the deposit ids with me i.e. 1, 2, 3. I have to update the users table with the respective deposits.

```
update users set balance = balance + (select amount from deposit where id = 1) where Id = (select userid from deposit where id = 1);
update users set balance = balance + (select amount from deposit where id = 2) where Id = (select userid from deposit where id = 2);
update users set balance = balance + (select amount from deposit where id = 3) where Id = (select userid from deposit where id = 3);
```

The above code works. But can we make the above query in one single query may be using IN operator provided we have deposit ids like 1, 2, 3. Please suggest your insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must join the tables in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
update users u
inner join deposit d on d.userid = u.id
set u.balance = u.balance + d.amount
where d.id in (1, 2, 3)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b2e11adbfac83b5f7000ea14f6d335f4).
Results:

```
> id | name | balance
> -: | :--- | ------:
>  5 | john |   10500
>  7 | mike |   13000
>  8 | jane |    7180
```

Answer (score 1):

A multi table update should do see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

```
update users join deposit on users.id = deposit.userid
set balance = balance + amount;
```

I wasn't clear why you were limiting to 1,2,3 so I left that out , you can add a where condition if necessary. If you want to track the last deposit updated to users I suggest you add a column to users to log it.

Answer (score 1):

A join between the users and deposit table using the user ID will do what you need. That way it automatically selects which values from the deposit table to use based on the join condition:

```
UPDATE 
  users u 
INNER JOIN deposit d 
  ON d.userid = u.id 
SET 
  balance = u.balance + d.amount 
WHERE 
  d.id IN (1,2,3);
```

Working demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dad9b716fa0bf441ca9ed4f13df562a3

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be safe, you should use:

```
update users u join
       (select userid, sum(amount) as amount
        from deposit d
        group by userid
       ) d
       on u.id = d.userid
    set balance = balance + d.amount;
```

The aggregation in advance is very important if the `deposit` table can have multiple deposits from the same user.  Your question has no indication that this is not possible, although the sample data does not have such an example.

Note that your code goes id by id in the `deposit` table, so it does not have this problem.  You could also replace it with correlated subqueries:

```
update users u
    set balance = balance + (select sum(amount)
                             from deposit d
                             where d.userid = u.id
                            ) 
    where exists (select 1
                  from deposit d
                  where d.userid = u.id
                 ) ;
```